# How to print the output of rsync when running from within a bash script

Tags: linux, bash, shell, rsync

I currently have a bash script that helps me rsync a file.

```bash
# Copy the file over
echo "* Downloading: ${TARGET_FILE_NAME}"
rsync -vh --progress --stats "$TARGET_FILE_PATH" "$USER_PATH" | exit 1)
echo "* Downloading Complete}"
```

However when running the script I only see

```bash
* Downloading SOME_FILE
* Downloading Complete
```

I would love to see the progress of the rsync.
I tried  `rsync .... 2>&1` but I can't seem to get the syntax right.

I've also tried :

`rsync -vh --progress --stats "$TARGET_FILE_PATH" "$USER_PATH" --log-file=/dev/stdout`
But this still doesn't print anything out.

I've also tried:

```
rsync -vh --progress --stats "$TARGET_FILE_PATH" "$USER_PATH" | while IFS= read -r line; do
   echo " $line"
done
```

But this just seems to print once rsync has completed.

Comment: Perhaps a syntax issue? Should `rsync -vh --progress --stats "$TARGET_FILE_PATH" "$USER_PATH" | exit 1)` be `rsync -vh --progress --stats "$TARGET_FILE_PATH" "$USER_PATH" || exit 1`?

Comment: In your first example you do `rsync ... | exit 1`. You are piping the stdout of `rsync` into the `exit` command. Presumably you meant to use `|| exit 1`. But, frankly, it is simpler and safer to just do `set -o errexit` at the top of your script and omit the `|| exit 1`.

Comment: Both of these were the answer. Thank you.

Comment: @KurtisRader : While _errexit_ in this particular example indeed would help, I guess that the `rsync` is not the only command in a shell script, and recommending to use _errexit_ has a big chance of breaking the rest of the script. At least _errexit_ should not be recommended unless also pointing out its [perils](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashPitfalls#errexit).

Comment: @user1934428, You are wrong. I say this as a grey beard who has been programming since the mid 1970's. The article you linked to has serious problems. Using `set -o errexit` is always the appropriate thing to do. You should explicitly handle commands that might exit with a non-zero status where that is not indicative of a fatal error. Rather than implicitly letting commands fail silently and only handle some failures explicitly. Your approach is why there are so many security bugs and unexpected behavior of computer programs.

Comment: @user1934428, I'll also point out that the use of `||` and `&&` in a script should always be avoided. Experience has taught me that those syntactic shortcuts are fine when used interactively but obfuscate the behavior of scripts. Furthermore, I sometimes see both used in the same statement (e.g., `a || b && c`) which is always a red flag and unlikely to result in the desired behavior. When doing code reviews I never allow their use in a script.

Comment: Hey, don't knock us grey beards -- we've earned it `:)`

Comment: @KurtisRader, I could not possibly disagree more about `set -o errexit` being simpler or safer. See https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises; `set -e` is _terse_, certainly, but it has a wide array of behaviors that are unintuitive, context-dependent and version-dependent; as such, it makes nontrivial code almost impossible to desk-check for correctness. (Also see https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/various/set-e/).

Comment: @KurtisRader, ...When you're doing a code review it's much easier to look for missing `|| exit`s or `|| return`s than it is to look for cases where `set -e` is depended on to work consistently in a function where the "checked" flag will be set, suppressing its behavior, in some but not all calls. The less context one needs to keep in one's head during a code review to accurately assess code's safety, the more likely that review will be correct.

Comment: @AlbertoLerdo, as for piping to `while read` causing output to be delayed, the problem there is that when stdout isn't going to a TTY, it's fully-buffered by default. You can use `stdbuf -o0` or `stdbuf -oL` to work around that. Also note that it's very common for programs to change how much verbose output they write based on the current value of `isatty(1)` or `isatty(2)`, removing things like progress bars when output is going to a file or pipeline instead of direct to a terminal. If _that's_ the case you can work around it with `unbuffer`.

Answer (score 1):

To capture the output of `rsync` and print it immediately while the transfer is ongoing, you can use the following approach.

```
#!/bin/bash

TARGET_FILE_PATH="source_path/target_file"
USER_PATH="destination_path/"
TARGET_FILE_NAME="target_file"

# Copy the file over
echo "* Downloading: ${TARGET_FILE_NAME}"
rsync -vh --progress --stats "$TARGET_FILE_PATH" "$USER_PATH" &
RSYNC_PID=$!

# Wait for the rsync process to finish and capture its output
wait "$RSYNC_PID"
EXIT_STATUS=$?

if [ $EXIT_STATUS -eq 0 ]; then
    echo "* Downloading Complete"
else
    echo "* Downloading Failed"
fi
```

In this script, we start the `rsync` command in the background using & and store its process ID (PID) in the `RSYNC_PID` variable. Then, we use the wait command to wait for the `rsync` process to finish.

By running the `rsync` process in the background, the script can continue to execute and display messages like "* Downloading: ..." and "* Downloading Complete" while `rsync` is running. The progress and output of `rsync` will be displayed as usual because it's running in the same terminal.

After the `rsync` process finishes, we capture its exit status in the `EXIT_STATUS` variable and display  **Downloading Complete or Downloading Failed** accordingly.